# Partitioned drive Permission

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, hard-drive, chown

So I added a second drive for to use for back-ups. I changed the ownership, when I try to use the partition, it says that I do not have permission. Here is what mount is showing.

```
/dev/sdb3 on /media/ronharp/File Backup type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
gvfsd-fuse on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That message isn't an error. What is the error message and when exactly does it happen? Also, what did you change the owner to? Did you also set the access permissions?

Comment: I used chown -r to take possession of the partition. The error is that when I try to use the partition I get a message saying that I do not have permission to add a folder or file.

Comment: What was the command you ran, exactly?

Comment: I wish I could remember. That was two weeks ago.  Sorry I suck at this. lol

Comment: Well, was it like `sudo chown -R username /dev/sdX`, or was it just what you said above: `sudo chown -r`? Do you have a tutorial you followed? Why did you `chown` the drive in the first place?

Comment: It was with the use name and partition. I used this site and searched for hard drive partition ownership and followed the outline on one of the threads. That is why I used chown.

Comment: But what made you think that you needed to change ownership to yourself?

Comment: I am the sole user. Who else would I change the ownership to?

Comment: What made you think that you needed to change the ownership in the first place? Could you not edit files or something?

Comment: On another note: how many commands have you entered since the `chown`? Like, 10, 15, 10000?

Comment: Exactly. The partition is new. There is nothing on it. I cannot add anything to it. It says I am not the owner of the file.  Probably about 5 commands.

Comment: OK. Open a terminal and just press the up arrow until you come to the `chown` command. [edit] your question and paste it in.

Comment: sudo chown ronharp:ronharp /media/user/72086381-1f2a-4a94-9eb0-3627d61f83a7

Comment: Hang on. Did you put the path as `/media/user/`? `user` needs to be your username.

Comment: Must not have. How can I fix this? would it be easier to delete the partition and start over?

Comment: I'm going to say yes. Open Gparted (installed by default) and use it to format the partition. If you only use it for Ubuntu, use `ext4`. If it's going to be used with Ubuntu and Windows, however, use `NTFS`. If it's going to be used on Ubuntu and Mac, or all three OSes, use `FAT32`.

Comment: Deleted and recreated. It is a ext 4.

Comment: Did it work out?

Comment: NO, IT will not let me create a folder in the partition

Comment: It is owned by root.

Comment: OK, this time, run `sudo chown username:username /media/username/driveUUID` then `sudo chmod -R 755 /same/path`.

Comment: /dev/sdb3: LABEL="Back-up" UUID="a26f5530-d444-4cc4-93bc-6393563f6e7a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6cb7b25e-03"
ronharp@ronharp-Latitude-E6530:~$ sudo chown ronharp:ronharp /media/ronharp/a26f5530-d444-4cc4-93bc-6393563f6e7a Did not work for some reason.
chown: cannot access ‘/media/ronharp/a26f5530-d444-4cc4-93bc-6393563f6e7a’: No such file or directory

Comment: Run `sudo mount /dev/sdb3`

Answer (score 0):

First you check with the partition which you have to give the permission to access by opening the terminal and typing....

`sudo fdisk -l`

And format the partitioned drive by....

`sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb3 /media`

(`/dev/sdb3`  is the example which I have given here, check with yours)

And enter into the superuser mode....

`sudo su`

and enter your password

Copy the address of your partitioned drive by opening the file manager (basically nautilus) and press ctrl+l for the appereance of the address bar.

Paste that with

`chmod +x paste-it-here`

in the terminal and proceed further, you will get the privilage to get access to it.

And don't forget to exit the superuser mode by typing `exit`.

Even I got the same problem and solved it on my own, GParted didn't helped me any ways.